# Angular is not bundling my css when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku, bulma

I am trying to use the Bulma node module (`npm install bulma`) with an angular project using the angular-cli project generator.

.ancular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
      ],
```

When I run `ng build` or `ng build -prod` on my local machine, the css is all bundled up nicely as expected.

When I do `ng build -prod` in my `postinstall` script that gets run when I deploy to Heroku, my app builds with no problems, but only `styles.css` is included in `bundle.styles.css`.

I have checked to make sure Bulma is installed before Heroku builds, and it is. The Heroku build log produces no errors (my local build log produces several warnings related to Bulma, so its as if its ignoring bulma entirely) even with `-v`. I have been unable to reproduce the scenario on my local machine.

Comment: I will suggest you use the Bulma CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bulma

Comment: While I appreciate the alternative, that doesn't solve the problem. What if I decide to use a css library that does not provide a CDN?